# Using ordered dict tuples as find&replace patterns

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to use a dictionary as a find&replace patterns set to be applied to another dictionary with keys and values as strings.

I have two dictionaries. First one is an ordered dictionary (collections.OrderedDict) with tuples that are the above mentioned find&replace patterns.

A fragment of this dictionary looks like this:

```
dict1 = 
{
('e0', 'i0'),
('o0', 'a0'),
('t sj a0$', 'ts a0'),
('tj sj a0$', 'ts a'),
('([bvgdzklmnprstfh])j a0', '\\1j i0'),
('([^s])j a0$', '\\1j i0')
}
```

As you can see, some of these patterns are simply strings, some of them contain RegEx special characters. This dict has to be ordered, because many of its patterns have to be applied in a specific order. Standard dict, as far as I know, is doing it "randomishly".

Second one looks like this:

```
dict2 =
{
'обнёсшим': 'o0 b nj o1 s sh i0 m',
'колыхалось': 'k o0 l y0 h a1 l o0 sj',
'непроизводительностях': 'nj e0 p r o0 i0 z v o0 dj i1 tj e0 lj n o0 s tj a0 h',
'цукаемою': 'ts u0 k a1 j e0 m o0 j u0',
'соревнующееся': 's o0 rj e0 v n u1 j u0 sch e0 j e0 sj a0',
'сорганизовано': 's o0 r g a0 nj i0 z o1 v a0 n o0'
}
```

My goal is to iterate over first dict (dict1) and check, if any of find patterns (first element of each tuple) is found in the second's dictionary (dict2) values. If yes, I want each of them to be replaced with replace patterns (second element of each tuple).

I have this script which almost does the job. It works, if I'm not using RegEx special characters. It doesn't work for any of $, [], [^], \1 and many others (which is quite strange, because I've tried my patterns for some strings in Python3 console).

```
for find, replace in dict1.items():
    for g, p in dict2.items():
        if find in p:
            dict2[g] = re.sub(find, replace, dict2[g])
```

Expected result is to get these RegEx patterns work.

Comment: Your first dictionary can be a list if order matters and you're just planning on iterating over it with `items()` (although, yes, Python 3.6+ guarantees ordering of dicts). Also, use raw strings to preserve regex special characters.

Comment: Raw strings didn't work anyway, because of the `if find in p:` line, as @Khalid Ali has pointed out. So tuples inside a list stay in the order they were put into a list? I wouldn't have to use OrderedDict then.

Comment: Yes, not to mention iterating over a dictionary to check against values defeats the purpose of lookup in a dictionary (dict ops should be O(1), not linear). I'm only mentioning these as factors to simplify the code, not a solution to the main problem. I couldn't quite tell what your expected output was, but I'm glad it worked out!

Comment: Thank you. All fo sudden another problem occured. I don't know why, but my fixed code (with the Khalid Ali's improvement) stopped working. My output strings include some RegEx "leftovers", like: `a0 \1j \1j i0 v a1 f \1h i0 j i0 sj a0`. I'll start a new question, I guess.
EDIT:
Nevermind, it was multi "\" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code in this line `if find in p:`.

When you use RegEx special syntax such as `a0$` the if statement will never be `True`, you could instead use regex compile/search for this check instead of the `in` membership test operation, or remove the `if` statement all together.

Comment: I did what you wrote, and it worked. So, as far as I understand, getting rid of the `if` statement here will make the code to run a sort of hidden `if` anyway, basically, if there's a match in `re.sub(find, replace, dict2[g])` -- do it, if there's not, do nothing, right?

Comment: Correct, the substitution would only occur if the regex pattern found in the target string.